# Tor Browser on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I have done extensive research, and yet there is no straightforward way to install the tor browser bundle on ubuntu 13.10 to work. Can anybody help me install the tor browser bundle?

Acer Aspire V5 
Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Yes, I will look into that right now.

Comment: Tried most of that, it seems like the newer version doesn't work with those commands.

Comment: have you tried the instructions on the tor website? https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Comment: I think I've got it. I thought about it for a while, and looked at the install process again and found out that Ubuntu 13.10 does not run executable text files, so I used dconf to change it to ask. Sorry about this. I'm fairly new to ubuntu, had to reinstall it several times.

Comment: it's alright, but try to search the site next time and include all steps you've taken in your next question. So will it be easier for us to help you. :)

Comment: @Alvar This shouldn't be flagged as duplicate, because this is about the *tor browser bundle* while the other question which you refer to is about *tor*. The tor browser bundle is much easier to handle and setup.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a terminal prompt `<Ctl-T>` then type the following.. Tor should be fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```